# No default controller available bluetoothctl

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 19.04, bluez

I am having a strange issue with my bluetooth (headset). It connect but then the connection drops only on HSP/HFP profile and I won't be able to connect again and Bluetooth is disabled and can't enable again -- A2DP profile works fine without disconnecting.

And the output of `journalctl --unit=bluetooth -f` the moment it drops is :

```
Aug 22 09:45:43 enigma bluetoothd[1094]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Aug 22 09:57:28 enigma bluetoothd[1094]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_A0_60_90_5D_20_C5/fd0: fd(25) ready
Aug 22 10:13:42 enigma bluetoothd[1094]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Aug 22 10:13:42 enigma bluetoothd[1094]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Aug 22 10:13:42 enigma bluetoothd[1094]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

And the output of `/var/log/syslog` the seconds connection drops.

```
Aug 22 10:13:45 enigma kernel: [ 1920.621889] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
Aug 22 10:13:45 enigma kernel: [ 1920.621936] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc05 tx timeout
Aug 22 10:13:43 enigma baloo_file.desktop[3762]: UdevQt: unhandled device action "bind"
Aug 22 10:13:48 enigma systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.service: Succeeded.
Aug 22 10:14:13 enigma dbus-daemon[1759]: [session uid=1000 pid=1759] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez.obex' unit='dbus-org.bluez.obex.service' requested by ':1.101' (uid=1000 pid=7636 comm="gnome-control-center " label="unconfined")
```

And it's running when checking the status

```
~ systemctl status bluetooth.service
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-08-22 11:15:36 EET; 7min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 12348 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 852.0K
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─12348 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

To get the bluetooth work again, i have tried solutions from similar questions but none of them worked for me.

Only reloading kernel modules makes bluetooth work again and I was able to connect again to the headset with.

```
$ sudo rmmod btusb
$ sudo modprobe btusb
```

But it's still frustrating to spend some time while you are in a call and then reload the module to get it work again

Appreciate your help